# How to use exec() with new lines in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, newline

I have a website that just sends a couple of lines of Python. I use requests to connect to this site and get it, but it has \n in it. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
import requests
r = r.get("www.example.com")
t = r.text
exec(t)
```

The variable t has new lines. Here is the error:

```
>>> exec(t)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    import time\nprint(time.time())
                              ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Another thing: On the webpage that it is retrieved from, it is a \n, but the value of t had \n rather than \n. I am not sure what I can do to fix this.

Comment: executing python code returned from a get request sounds like a terrible idea

Comment: It's my own site.

Comment: Your request text **does not** contain newlines. Likely it contain backslash literal followed by n.

Comment: As other commenter said, executing Python code sent by the browser is a very bad idea, even if it is your own site.  Just because it's your own site won't stop a nefarious person from reading your HTML and/or Javascript, figuring out what requests it sends to your server, and writing their own version that you never expected.  The only time it's safe to do something like this is if it's a test prototype with local access only and you are the only user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your string actually contained a newline, this would work fine. The string you are getting back from the server **does not even contain a newline** - it instead contains, literally, "\n". See this example below demonstrating this:

```
>>> t = 'import time\\nprint(time.time())'
>>> exec(t)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    import time\nprint(time.time())
                                  ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
>>> t = 'import time\nprint(time.time())'
>>> exec(t)
1491841224.27
```

Notice how the first line contains a literal "\n", while the second time I define `t` I actually use a real newline. In the first example, it gives the exact same error as you are getting, leading me to believe that that is your problem.

So, to fix this, you either will have to modify the server (since you claim it's your website) to return data with actual newlines, or, if you don't want to (or can't) modify the server, you will have to replace the "\n"s with actual newlines or with semicolons. One way to do this is like `t.replace('\\n', '\n')`. So your code, if you decided to fix it in this roundabout way, would look like:

```
import requests
r = r.get("www.example.com")
t = r.text
exec(t.replace('\\n', '\n'))
```

But, if you fixed the website, your code could look exactly the same as in your question and work fine.

Comment: OP also ask for a fix.  i.e.  `t.replace('\\n', '\n')`

Comment: Thanks. It solved my problem. How could I fix the website, though? I mean what is the difference between a literal \n and a newline?

Comment: @apoorlydrawnape I have no idea, since you haven't posted the code of your website or anything like that. That's completely out of the scope of this question, regardless. If you want help with that, ask a new question with relevant tags and code. Also, a "\n" is just a sequence of two characters. A newline is a binary value which can be represented as "\n" in some programming languages.

Comment: Okay. It's not really necessary now as long as this works.